# API updates and Wi-Fi network connection

Tags: camera, sony

I've been looking through the API docs and support forum.  Based on what I've been reading, there are two big holes in the Sony camera stack:

1) Cameras ONLY support master mode (peer-to-peer) wi-fi connections. They do not support infrastructure mode allowing the camera to connect to existing wi-fi networks.

2) API does not support moving files off the camera.

My questions:  Does Sony plan to address add these capabilities?  If yes, what is the timeline?

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest.

(EDITED: multi Wi-Fi connection is used by Live View Remote LVR & Camera Remote API is officially NOT supported in multi Wi-Fi mode). 
Sony lens style cameras QX1, QX30 and ActionCams HDR-AZ1, HDR-AS100V can connect to existing Wi-Fi networks (Multi Connection Wi-Fi mode). Please check if your Wi-Fi network is compatible with connection method used. Newer QX1, QX30, HDR-AZ1 cameras support content transfer API. Please check API Reference document for exact APIs. Best Regards, Prem, Developer World team.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Reading the API docs, it's still not clear that you can connect the camera to an access point.

Comment: I'd like to connect control the camera with a nodejs app.  Not clear in the docs about support for connecting to an access point (AP).  Thanks for the information.  Reading the API docs, it's still not clear that you can connect the camera to an access point.  I'm interested in building a nodejs app to control the camera and transfer files. ... https://developer.sony.com/2013/11/29/how-to-develop-an-app-using-the-camera-remote-api-2/